# Yast2 Software Management crashes - openSUSE Leap 15

Tags: opensuse, yast

I am unable to open Software Management from the Yast2 ui.

Opening from the terminal, following `su -` I can see these errors:

```
penguin:\~ # yast2
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root
Run command: /sbin/yast2 sw_single 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YUIPluginExceptio
what(): Couldn't load plug-in q
/sbin/yast2: line 455: 25386 Aborted (core dumped) $ybindir/y2start $module "$@" "$SELECTED_GUI" $Y2_GEOMETRY $Y2UI_ARGS
```

And attempting to use the ncurses interface, with `sudo yast2`, after trying to open the Software Manager I see a few problems:

Couldn't load plug-in ncurses-pkg Check the log file!

then

```
Error Internal error. Please report a bug report with logs. Run save_y2logs to get complete logs. Details: Opening package selector failed. Caller: /usr/share/YaST2/modules/PackagesUI.rb:316:in \RunPackageSelector'
```

But note:

```
$ _ zypper in libyui-ncurses-pkg8
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libyui-ncurses-pkg8' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'libyui-ncurses-pkg8-2.48.5.2-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

and

```
_ zypper se libyui-ncurses                                                                                                                    
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name                     | Summary                                                   | Type
---+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------
   | libyui-ncurses-devel     | Libyui-ncurses header files                               | package
   | libyui-ncurses-doc       | Libyui-ncurses documentation                              | package
   | libyui-ncurses-pkg       | Libyui - yast2 package selector widget for the ncurses UI | srcpackage
   | libyui-ncurses-pkg-devel | Libyui-ncurses-pkg header files                           | package
   | libyui-ncurses-pkg-doc   | Libyui-ncurses-pkg documentation                          | package
   | libyui-ncurses-pkg-doc   | Libyui-ncurses-pkg documentation                          | srcpackage
i+ | libyui-ncurses-pkg8      | Libyui - yast2 package selector widget for the ncurses UI | package
   | libyui-ncurses-pkg9      | Libyui - yast2 package selector widget for the ncurses UI | package
   | libyui-ncurses-tools     | Libyui-ncurses tools                                      | package
i+ | libyui-ncurses8          | Libyui - Character Based User Interface                   | package
i  | libyui-ncurses9          | Libyui - Character Based User Interface                   | package
```

The tarball that is created when running save_y2logs has a lot of files in it. I'm not sure how to make sense of them

For info:

```
$ _ zypper ls
# | Alias | Name | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh | Type
---+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+-------
1 | http-download.opensuse.org-17cfaabf | openSUSE:Factory | Yes | (r ) Yes | Yes | rpm-md
2 | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1 | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1 | Yes | (r ) Yes | Yes | rpm-md
3 | packman | packman | Yes | (r ) Yes | Yes | rpm-md
4 | repo-debug | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Debug | No | ---- | ---- | NONE
5 | repo-debug-non-oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Debug-Non-Oss | No | ---- | ---- | NONE
6 | repo-debug-update | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Debug | No | ---- | ---- | NONE
7 | repo-debug-update-non-oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Debug-Non-Oss | No | ---- | ---- | NONE
8 | repo-non-oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Non-Oss | Yes | (r ) Yes | Yes | rpm-md
9 | repo-source | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Source | No | ---- | ---- | NONE
10 | repo-source-non-oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Source-Non-Oss | No | ---- | ---- | NONE
11 | repo-update | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update | Yes | (r ) Yes | Yes | rpm-md
12 | repo-update-non-oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Non-Oss | Yes | (r ) Yes | Yes | rpm-md
```

I have run `zypper clean`, `zypper ref`, `zypper up`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the `openSUSE:Factory` repo is actually a Tumbleweed (Not Leap) repo, and when updating packages, I ended up in some mixed state between the two distributions, which caused many things to be broken. I'm unsure how I got into this state. But there you have it.

The options at this point were either to remove the `Factory` repo and `zypper dup` to attempt to move back onto Leap (this did not work), rollback using `snapper` (this did not work), or upgrade to Tumbleweed, which seems to have resolved my issues. The only remaining options would be a full re-install of Leap.

The upgrade was pretty easy, following these docs: 
https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Tumbleweed_upgrade

Simply just:

```
mkdir /etc/zypp/repos.d/old
mv /etc/zypp/repos.d/*.repo /etc/zypp/repos.d/old
```

to remove and back up the old mess of repos I was on

```
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss repo-oss
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/non-oss repo-non-oss
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/debug repo-debug
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/update/tumbleweed/ repo-update
```

to add the correct Tumbleweed repos

```
zypper dup
```

to upgrade. As always: back up before a distribution upgrade. But I didn't encounter any immediate or obvious issues with data loss.

Answer (score 2):

Although the OP was able to resolve this and other problems with a system upgrade, a more targeted fix would be to investigate the `y2log` (which is also copied into the archive mentioned in the question):

```sh
sudo cat /var/log/YaST2/y2log
```

Based on the information given in the question, for the OP this would have almost certainly revealed that Software Management was looking for YUI 9 when only YUI 8 was installed.  That problem could be fixed by upgrading the appropriate packages from the command line:

```sh
sudo zypper install libyui-qt9 libyui-qt-pkg9
```

A similar fix would help with `ncurses` for anyone wanting to work with a TUI.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you clarify how you reached this conclusion?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am merely reporting the fix for me to a problem with matching symptoms.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: OK.  The answer seemed to suggest that you were pretty sure the OP's problem had the same cause, so I thought you might have determined that from the information in the question, and those details might help another user identify the problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 Oh I see.  I am pretty sure on account of "what(): Couldn't load plug-in q" appearing in the question, which is a cutoff version of the error message that pointed me at `libyui-qt9`.